# Why do people turn and face the bomb?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I have tested if the bomb is facing you or not and the damage is the same. Is just for fun? It seems like you have a higher chance of dying if you face the bomb because you have to take time to turn around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the History of CS there is the phenomenon that if you turn and do not face the Bomb when it Explodes the damage done to you will be reduced. This was until CS:Go, they removed this feature from the game. You will see that most people even high Skilled player do so because they are used to it or they just don't know

Proof:

Comment: Where is the proof that it does so in a other cs?

Comment: there are also Videos of that but in short you can simply trust the wiki: counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/C4 Section 6-Trivia

Answer (score 2):

We do it because a lot of us old school players are/were under the impression that it deals less damage. We turn and look at the bomb as it explodes just out of habit.. Same as how we nervously switch to knife a lot. Quickswitch a lot. Drop guns at starts and halfs.
  I even catch myself trying to crouch run still when Im in a hurry and dont want to make noise(it doesnt work in go, though).

They are just old habits, man. We cant help them. A lot of us have been playing this game for about a decade, now. Muscle memory and shit.

I think that the best and most important part about them is that most of the quirky habits OG CS players have involve rapid movements and/or button presses. I think it helps to keep your reflexes quick and your mind fresh.